# Is it possible to modify innertext of an element with simpleHTMLdom and save the modified content to local file?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have a php process that uses simpleHTMLdom to load an HTML page, parse all the content and read all instances of a specific class of DIVs.

I then creates a PHP array (multidimensional) of data from those DIVs and UL / LI elements contained in each of them.  All this works perfect and I have the data I need.

I then insert a NEW array object / item into the array using json_decode (from JSON that is posted to this page/process), and perform a 'sort' on the array based on a timestamp.

What I'm trying to do now is take the html that I previously loaded with simpleHTMLdom and

1.) empty the parent element that contains all the DIVs I previously built the array from:

```
$html->find('.bodycontent')->innertext = '';
```

2.) use PHP foreach loop to loop over my array and re-build all the DIVs and add to the HTML element that I previously emptied:

```
// variable to hold the new HTML content
$newHTMLforMeetings = '';  

// loop over array and build HTML...
foreach($articles as $addMeetingItem){
    $newHTMLforMeetings .= '<div class="meetingEntry">';
    $newHTMLforMeetings .= '    <h2 class="meetingEntryTitle">'.$addMeetingItem['meetingTitle'].'</h2>';
    $newHTMLforMeetings .= '    <div class="meetingEntryDate">'.$addMeetingItem['meetingDate'].'</div>';
    $newHTMLforMeetings .= '    <div class="meetingEntryDocs">';
    $newHTMLforMeetings .= '        <ul class="meetingDocs">';
        foreach( $addMeetingItem['meetingDocs'] as $key => $aDoc ){
            $newHTMLforMeetings .= '<li class="docliItem"> <a href="'. $addMeetingItem['meetingDocLinks'][$key] .'" class="meetingLink">'. $aDoc .'</a> </li>';
        }
    $newHTMLforMeetings .= '        </ul>';
    $newHTMLforMeetings .= '    </div>';
    $newHTMLforMeetings .= '</div>';
};

// **  THIS IS NOT WORKING FOR ME FOR SOME REASON **
// now add that newly built HTML content into the HTML element that was previously emptied
$html->find('.bodycontent')->innertext = $newHTMLforMeetings;
```

3.) take the newly modified HTML content from simpleHTMLdom and save it to a local file:

```
// a new variable that has all the HTML I want to save
$docHtml = $html->save();

// save out the HTML content to the local file
file_put_contents('NewPage.html', $docHtml);
```

I can echo out the $newHTMLforMeetings and it looks perfect and contains all my HTML elements and data.   But the page that I save does not contain the new elements / HTML content... but the container I'm trying to insert them into IS emptied, so that IS working.

What do I need to do to add my HTML content then save the document and be able to see my new content in place?

(I'm also now starting to think that instead of destroying and rebuilding ALL the DIVs, I should just use simpleHTMLdom to traverse all the DIVs and determine the proper location my newly added DIV should be in, then insert it at the right location... I'll revisit this later, so for now the question will just focus on removing all the DIVs and rebuilding each from my array of data.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want:

```
$html->find('.bodycontent', 0)->innertext = $newHTMLforMeetings;
```

remember that

```
$html->find('.bodycontent')
```

will return an array, and

```
$html->find('.bodycontent', $i)
```

will return an element

Comment: Awesome, works great and I'll note that distinction between what returns an array vs. element.